# Simple https proxy

Tags: python, sockets, proxy

I am trying to proxy requests with python, I can proxy http requests easily, http payload comes and and turns back. But I couldn't get it working with https, it doesn't work the same way. I guess it has something to do with `CONNECT` method. Here is the current state of my code and my shot with https in commented lines.

```py
import socket, ssl
from threading import Thread

class Proxy:
    def __init__(self, port=3000):
        self.port = port
        self.proxy_sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
        self.proxy_sock.setsockopt(socket.SOL_SOCKET, socket.SO_REUSEADDR, 1)
        self.buffer_size = 4096

    def run(self):
        self.proxy_sock.bind(("0.0.0.0", self.port))
        self.proxy_sock.listen(100)
        print("  * Proxy server is running on port {}".format(self.port))

        while True:
            client, addr = self.proxy_sock.accept()
            print(" => {}:{}".format(addr[0], addr[1]))
            Thread(target=self.process_request, args=(client,), daemon=True).start()
    
    def process_request(self, client):
        payload = client.recv(self.buffer_size)
        host = payload.decode().split("\r\n")[1].split(" ")[1]

        server = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
        server.connect((host, 80))
        server.sendall(payload)
        server_data = server.recv(4096)
        print(server_data)
        server.close()

        client.sendall(server_data)
        client.close()
    
    # def process_request(self, client):
    #     payload = client.recv(self.buffer_size)
    #     print(payload)
    #     host, port = payload.decode().split(" ")[1].split(":")
    #     port = int(port)
    #     print(host, port)

    #     context = ssl.SSLContext(ssl.PROTOCOL_TLSv1)

    #     server = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
    #     s_sock = context.wrap_socket(server, server_hostname=host)
    #     s_sock.connect((host, port))
    #     s_sock.send(f"GET / HTTP/1.1\r\nHost: {host}\r\n\r\n ".encode())
    #     server_data = s_sock.recv(4096)
    #     print(server_data)
    #     s_sock.close()

    #     client.sendall(server_data)
    #     client.close()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    proxy = Proxy(8383)
    proxy.run()
```

Here how I test it:

```py
# Https
import requests
requests.get("https://google.com", proxies={"http": "http://127.0.0.1:8383", "https": "http://127.0.0.1:8383"})

# Http
import requests
requests.get("http://google.com", proxies={"http": "http://127.0.0.1:8383", "https": "http://127.0.0.1:8383"})
```

Comment: wow! this is cool nice job  I was just playing with this yesterday :P

Comment: *"Doesn't work"*  plus a code dump is not a useful problem description. Looking at the code I can see no attempt to properly deal with the CONNECT request, which suggests that you are missing the understanding of how CONNECT actually works. Therefore marked as duplicate of several questions which started with a similar misunderstanding and where the answers contain information about how CONNECT really works.

Comment: It basically is not a code dump, it should work with python version 3 on many computers. There is no proper attempt to deal with CONNECT for sure as I stated, I just don't know how to handle CONNECT.